# Find repeating sensor pattern of fixed length

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to decode an RF sensor output which consists of 72 pulses repeated 12 times.

Due to medium unreliability, some bits might be corrupted, the sentence might start mid-way, the end might be missing. But a successful decoding would happen if 3 sequences are repeated.

The input of the program is an array of delays between edge changes. Bit 0 has 2 pulses: 500(±249) followed by 1000(±249). Bit 1 has 2 pulses, 500(±249) followed by 2000(±249). The tolerance can be set to anything that still makes sense.

The start of a sequence is triggered by a long pulse (>3000) but this might be missing.

In a sequence there are 36 bits (72 pulses), bit 10 is a zero, bits 25-28 are all ones. Again, a reliable decoding can occur after 3 correct patterns are detected.

Example data (newlines are added for clarity):

```
642 73 369 88 304 136 297 106 308 119 278 111 287 119 293 116 287 129 129 2054 1897 588 1830 614 588 645 382 98 97 619 337 634 463 106 285 1000 449 798 1647 1008 468 793 609 857 180 
863 593 796 663 833 649 775 671 748 722 714 749 724 750 693 1757 639 1805 701 1741 660 799 685 1755 688 778 673 798 670 796 652 1792 645 1804 611 1828 632 1816 623 823 648 824 629 1816 644 813 643 1808 629 833 625 1826 601 1835 

615 3791 607 844 604 1836 618 1823 613 1821 638 1811 610 855 586 1859 602 853 618 1835 
604 859 611 844 619 856 595 863 604 867 591 882 590 868 537 1947 510 1928 516 1882 610 865 596 1853 587 858 609 868 587 869 603 1842 596 1844 601 1839 601 1841 598 876 582 875 596 1844 597 875 576 1866 569 911 572 1845 608 1836 

595 3800 587 875 596 1856 589 1842 592 1855 588 1849 601 870 584 1860 577 879 597 1845 593 881 572 884 589 883 576 881 576 902 553 899 584 886 573 1871 584 1863 574 1852 588 884 561 1882 565 891 581 896 558 905 567 1869 577 1863 577 1865 584 1858 583 886 566 938 488 1950 497 977 497 1921 549 887 583 1865 582 1851
```

Decoding the above:

```
642 73 369 88 304 136 297 ...
^ garbage pulses              ^
615 3791 607 844 604 1836 618 1823 613 1821 638 1811 610 855 586 1859 602 853 618 1835
     ^start  0       1        1        1        1        0       1        0       1
```

There is a suggested solution at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-repeating-and-non-overlapping-substring/ which can be adapted to work.

The integer array should probably be first converted to a binary array, taking the longest sequence between valid pulses (either a one or a zero).

The brute-force approach of O(n2+n) of finding the the repeating pattern plus another search for valid pattern (bits 10, 25-28) works, but I'm looking to optimize the solution.

The data is sent each ~80 seconds, likely with different content each time:

```
[noise] [long pulse] [sequence 1] [sequence 2] ... [sequence 12] [noise or no signal for ~80 seconds] [long pulse] ...
```

The detector might wake up in the middle of a sequence train:

```
[sequence 3 end] [sequence 4] [corrupted sequence 5] [sequence 6] [sequence 7] [incomplete sequence 8]
```

Sequences 1 through 12 represent identical data of 36 bits.
Valid binary sequence format:

```
xxxxxxxxx0xxxxxxxxxxxxxx1111xxxxxxxx
```

Where x represents the bits to be decoded, the other ones are fixed.

**As a sidenote**, the purpose is to decode a weather sensor using EspPiLight, running on a microcontroller. The senders have a random delay between messages, to avoid collision and due to manufacturing tolerances. The tolerance is also mostly due to manufacturing tolerances and temperature-dependent oscillators. The decoding is non-critical, false positives and negatives are acceptable. Since several decoder algorithms run in real-time, on a microcontroller, performance is prioritized, e.g. by exiting early if garbage data is detected.

Comment: I suppose delay variabilities are always referred to the previous pulse, right? So, if I have a bit 0, I would get first a value between 400 and 600 and then a value between 800 and 1200.

Comment: Are the *average* sums of doublets guaranteed to be 1500 and 2500? (does the error accumulate?) Is the number of 1-bits equal to the number of 0-bits? (via the addition of check-bits)

Comment: The example data consists of 100 garbage samples followed by two sequences of 36 bits. But only a few of the bits in the two sequences actually meet the specified tolerances. So it's back to the drawing board. Either you need to widen the tolerances, or you need to tighten hardware timing.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you would want your function to return, if passing in the example data you provided. I'm having some trouble grasping the problem.

Comment: @vpaladino778 The input numbers represent a sequence of bits, with two numbers per bit. A 500 followed by a 3000 represents a start bit. A 500 followed by a 2000 represents a `1` bit. A 500 followed by a 1000 represents a `0` bit. A message consists of a start bit followed by 36 zeros and ones. The input is supposed to be 12 copies of the same message. However, the example data only has some garbage followed by 2 copies of a message. The output from the algorithm should be the message, or a failure indication. The output for the example is  `0111 1010 1000 0000 1110 1000 1111 0010 1011`

Comment: So for example `615 3791` is a start bit? followed by `607 844` that is a 0 and `604 1836` is a 1?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_code#Trellis_diagram comes close (or: Viterbi) (I would start by reconstructing the signal , oversampling at eg 100 tics)

Comment: @KamilCuk That's my interpretation, although you'll notice that none of those values are within the ±100 tolerances given in the question.

Comment: @vpaladino778: user3386109 is right with his example, the tolerances might be wider/narrower, depending on the signal. Since the timings are so far apart, a tolerance of 250 should be ok. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: @user3386109 I will widen the tolerances in the question, but your example is spot on.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk that's correct.

Comment: @wildplasser thank you the the suggestion. Oversampling is not really an option since the signal repeats every ~80 seconds, possibly with different data. Only one burst contains the same data.

Comment: Why do you think you need an O(N*N) algoritm? You only need to classify pulse lengths , while keeping synchonised on the long pulses. Once a valid set of 72 semi-bits is received, you can decide to use it in your result (or not).

Comment: If you verify bits 25-28 without storing them, the message fits into a `uint32_t`, which makes it easy to compare with other copies of the message.

Comment: btw:I just solved your *problem*. Do you have a solution yet?

Comment: @user3386109 that's really cool, never thought of that

Comment: @wildplasser not yet, I'm just collecting solutions until I tackle it :)